# Can I ask the same doctrinal question across many different denominations?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I just asked [a question about marriage for Jehovah's witnesses](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4181/30). I could easily ask the same question regarding Roman Catholics, Methodists, Mormons, etc, and I would be very interested in the answers.

The answers for some denominations would be easier to find on Google, but for the ones which I can't find a straightforward answer, would this sort of practice be okay?
Obviously I would pace the questions instead of posting them all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, go for it!

I think you're coming at it with the right frame of mind. If the questions are too easy to find on Google (Catholics would be a good example), the question might not be the best for here. It'd probably be downvoted for "lack of research".

Also, I like that you would pace the questions.  I think this is a wise approach.

My only caveat... If you suspect that the marriage traditions for a couple of different groups are identical (say... Southern Baptists and American Baptists), you probably should lump them all together, when possible.  If you do that, it would be wise to ask if there are any significant differences between the denominations, though.  (Just in case there are.)

Obviously, Mormons and Quakers are going to have different standards, but LDS and RLDS will probably be the same.

Comment: RE: Catholic answers, our standards for good answers should be a lot higher than Google (I'd like to think so at least).  There's a lot of crap out there and furthermore that question (or a variant) comes up every week on http://relevantradio.com so a good answer would be pretty useful. But yeah, the question better be specific or else the answer will have to be in book format.

Comment: The idea is to limit questions that are "too simple".  That edict has been [handed down by Jeff](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/).  Catholicism was picked in my mind because I (more or less) knew the answer and because Google lead me [right here](http://nccbuscc.org/laity/marriage/marriagefaqs.shtml) on the first result.  It seemed sound, so I used Catholicism as an example of something that was "too simple".  Even then, the worst case scenario is that it might gain a few downvotes.